# Stack Overflow Careers - Can't select mileage

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

In Opera 28, Win 8, I can't select a mileage from the location distance dropdown - when I move my mouse over the `select` options, the popup vanishes.

> [image: careers-mileage-dropdown]

Comment: Reproduced with Chrome as well, latest version so it's not browser specific.

Comment: Thanks for the image @James. I wasn't sure if that was needed.

Comment: It was [ShadowWizard](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/152859/shadow-wizard) who added the image :) See [Revision History](http://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/253204/revisions) by clicking on the "edited" link in your question. I just corrected typo in the title.

Comment: Ooops, didn't think to check the edit history. Thanks for helping me improve my speling.

Comment: No problem, hope the team will see this soon and fix. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under Windows the select dropdown doesn't appear to bubble hover events up to the parent container. Our popup uses the `:hover` and `:focus` pseudo-classes to decide when it should display.

It also supports a couple of explicit classes `_focus` and `_hover` - I've added some JS which manually applies `_hover` when the the dropdown has focus which fixes the issue.

Thanks for the report :)

Comment: Ah, so much better. :) It's not that I don't like using my keyboard to navigate...I just like options.